# Unable to Initiate a VPN tunnel using IKEv2

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn, ike

I'm having an issue with a VPN tuunel between my Firewall (ASA 5516-X) and a third party firewall so I can't check the config in the second firewall. So I decide to debug my firewall and I realized that phase one wasn't complete and the only message that I get in the debug is:

**IKEv2-PLAT-2: Received PFKEY DPD for SPI 0xF671D605, error FALSE**

[image]

Searching for something else in the log I found that every time I apply the tunnel configuration the lines in the picture are shown:

[image]

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: if you turn on ikev2 debugging, you should get a lot more messages.  That message is about dead peer detection.

Comment: Is the only message I get during debug
`AsaTriara# debug crypto ikev2 protocol 200`
`AsaTriara# debug crypto ikev2 platform 200`

Comment: It doesn't look like either you or the peer is starting IKE negotiations.  I don't see any IKEv2 messages.  Maybe they're not using ikev2?